# Custom fields button on category pages

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-fields, posts

I have looked into http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields. And know how to target custom posts and output them on a page.
Now i need to create custom fields in all posts inside category.php and inside single.php.
I will make fields to be two buttons and later that will link to other pages.

However i can't find answer how i am supposed to add custom fields to specific category posts. Ofcourse every post with buttons will have a unique link.

**Could anyone point me in the right direction how i am supposed to create custom fields in all posts of a specific category?**

Comment: you can create custom field for all posts, not for posts of specific category. But you can use for specific category page

Comment: If you are working on default categories and posts of WordPress then you custom fields (i.e. custom_meta_boxes) will appear in all Posts. To make custom category at backend you need to register custom_post_type and custom Taxonomy to that custom post type. Then you will be able to have custom category with custom posts with custom fields. Keywords you are looking for, 'custom post type', 'register taxonomy for custom post type' and custom meta boxes for custom post type.